# Can I change the razor <text></text> syntax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is there a way to include custom functionality in the razor engine to augment the functionality it has?

For instance, if I wanted to use:

```
$(This is my text)
```

instead of

```
<text>This is my text</text>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Well...it's open source. And there are various hooks for customization which don't require changing the source if you are willing to dig into it (you can look at the source of [Meleze](https://github.com/meleze/Meleze.Web) for ideas). That said, you can use the `@:` syntax like @codingbiz suggests, or pick a semantically neutral HTML alternative as a wrapper. Seems like a high-effort/low-return task.

Comment: I don't know how to change razor syntax.  But I often use the @: operator and @helper functions to reduce <text></text> ugliness.  http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
<text>This is my text</text>
```

You can have

```
@:This is my text
```

This is how I do string literal without having to use the `<text>...</text>` tags. This is already provided by razor unless you want something else?

Comment: Awesome, that's just what I was looking for